# JQuery find() doesn't find elements inside angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an angular directive and I need to find all children with '.selected' class, but it's not working.

`element.parent().children()` :works fine

`element.parent().find('div')` : works fine

`element.parent().find('.selected')` : finds nothing.

How can I select the `<div class="child selected" test></div>` element?

Directive:

```
app.directive('test', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element(element).bind('mouseenter', function() {
            $('.parent').css('background-color', 'red');
            element.parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            element.addClass('selected');
        });
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child selected" test></div>
    <div class="child" test></div>
    <div class="child" test></div>
</div>
```

Comment: element.parent().find('selected').removeClass('selected');

Comment: @AshishPatel Doesn't work. Needs to find class named 'selected'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are relying on `jqLite` *lite version of jquery* then you have to go through the docs of [angular.elements](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) which can inform you that it has **some limitation** and as you are using `.find()` then here is it's limitation:

It can find the element with tag names only.

From the docs for `.find()`:

> jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. ***jqLite implements only the most commonly needed functionality*** with the goal of having a very small footprint.
>
> #### find() - Limited to lookups by tag name

Comment: Thanks, I had jQuery defined after angular also.

Comment: @user3743266 use `ngClass` to add class and find the element with tagname and do some script work.